# Regex Infinite Loop

Tags: regex, perl, loops

```
ABCD1234: X1 Wed, Fri 09:00 - 12:00 (Weeks:1-8)

ACD1234: S1 Wed 11:00 - 13:00 (Weeks:1-7,8-12), Fri 14:00 - 15:00 (Weeks:1-7,8-12), Fri 15:00 - 16:00 (Weeks:1-7,8-12)
```

In the first line, I would like to match:

`Wed` `09` `12`

`Fri` `09` `12`

In the second line, I would like to match:

`Wed` `11` `13`

`Fri` `14` `15`

`Fri` `15` `16`

In my `Perl` script I have:

```
 while ($line =~ m/(Mon|Tue|Wed|Thu|Fri).+?([0-9][0-9]):.+?- ([0-9][0-9])/){

    print "$1\n";
    print "$2\n";
    print "$3\n";
}
```

However, this is resulting in an infinite loop. I'm also not sure whether this is matching how I intend. I tried it out using RegExr (regexr.com).

Comment: Do you not want it to match Fri 15 16 too?

Comment: The infinite loop is caused by the `while` condition -- to prevent this happening, you need to use a modifier such as `g`; see [perlretut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html) for more info on modifiers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should capture in a lookahead, as seen from your first expected result:

`Wed` `09` `12`

`Fri` `09` `12`

The 2nd and 3rd capturing groups will repeat.

See this regex match:

```
/(Mon|Tue|Wed|Thu|Fri)(?=.+?([0-9][0-9]):.+?- ([0-9][0-9]))/g
```

```
ABCD1234: X1 Wed, Fri 09:00 - 12:00 (Weeks:1-8)

ACD1234: S1 Wed 11:00 - 13:00 (Weeks:1-7,8-12), Fri 14:00 - 15:00 (Weeks:1-7,8-12), Fri 15:00 - 16:00 (Weeks:1-7,8-12)
```

```
Match 1: [Group 1: Wed][Group 2: 09][Group 3: 12]
Match 2: [Group 1: Fri][Group 2: 09][Group 3: 12]
Match 3: [Group 1: Wed][Group 2: 11][Group 3: 13]
Match 4: [Group 1: Fri][Group 2: 14][Group 3: 15]
Match 5: [Group 1: Fri][Group 2: 15][Group 3: 16]
```

Here is a [regex demo](http://regex101.com/r/wP4jT8/1).

Comment: Thanks Unihedron. I was just wondering, why doesn't mine capture `Fri 09 12`?

Comment: @Giri because your regular expression matches the content as a match. When a match is completed, the pointer moves forward. With a lookahead, the numbers can be captured without moving the pointer.